# Can an editText know where it is in a gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

I am wondering if and how a view with-in a gridViewItem can return the location of the cell that it is in.

In example in my program I currently have a 8x8 gridview storing 64 editText views. The gridview is created by adapting an array of strings.

What I want to do is when the user enters something in the editText the array will update to that value at that location in the array.

Ex: When the user enters 12 in the 1st row of the 1st column then array[0]="12"

Currently my issue is that I do not know how to find the cell that the editText is in.

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Below is some relevant code:

The array:

```
private String[] numbers = new String[] {

"42", "0", "0", "39", "32", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "45", "0", "51",
        "36", "35", "20", "0", "22", "0", "53", "0", "1", "2", "0", "16",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "5",
        "6", "0", "0", "0", "57", "0", "0", "64", "7", "0", "0", "0" };
```

The adapter:

```
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridViewGame);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.item_layout,R.id.editTextGridItem, numbers);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Item_layout.xml

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/editTextGridItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:digits="1234567890"
android:gravity="center"
android:hint=""
android:inputType="phone"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
```

If you need to see more please let me know.

Comment: A gridview is just a container.  Your question is like asking the drawer, which pair of socks you just picked up.  You know the position in the grid because you put them there.  Store this position in the edittext, perhaps using the `Tag` property, then set their `addTextChangedListener` to a common method which reads the `Tag`.  Or maybe use a `Map` of some sort to hold a mapping between the edittext and it's position in the array.  Even better, extend editext to add row and column properties which you set when you add to the grid.

Comment: Ok that does sense but I am not placing them manually. They are being placed via a adapter. How can I tell the adapter to set each of them unique tags?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Added some code. Let me know if I missed anything relevant.

Comment: you need to override getView on your adapter and wire up the Listener there. There should be plenty of examples on how to do that.

Comment: you need to override getView on your adapter and wire up the Listener there. There should be plenty of examples on how to do that.